# Eliminating recursion in this Lua monad mimicry

Tags: haskell, recursion, lua, parsec

I'm trying to crudely replicate [Parsec](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec) in Lua, and I'm having a bit of trouble with the bind function <strike>being recursive</strike> generating recursive `runParser`s.

```
function Parser:bind(f)
    return new(function(s)
        local result = self.runParser(s)
        if result.cons() == Result.Success then
            return f(result.get()).runParser(result.get(2))
        else
            return result
        end
    end)
end
```

I'm using a custom system of making ADTs, hence the `cons()` and `get()` functions on the return value. The equivalent Haskell code would be something like this.

```
m >>= f = Parser $ \s -> case result of
                            Success a cs -> runParser (f a) cs
                            _ -> result
                        where
                            result = runParser m s
```

The argument to the `Parser` constructor (the `new` function in Lua) is the `runParser` function. So calling a different `runParser` from within `runParser` non-tail-recursively generates very deep call stacks, which causes a stack overflow. Any tips on removing the recursion or translating it to tail-recursion?

Comment: Convert to continuation-passing style (assuming Lua does tail call optimization).   I don't have time to elaborate right now, but maybe that will set you on the right track.

Comment: Perfect! I hadn't thought of that. Works great.

EDIT: Although, my Lua implementation has a bug where tail calls don't update stack information correctly, so getting an error anywhere in the stack produces terribly incorrect error messages. But that's a different problem! =P

Comment: @WillFancher I suggest you add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuation passing made this very easy to solve.

```
function Parser:bind(f)
    return new(function(s, cont)
        return self.runParser(s, function(result)
            if result.cons() == Result.Success then
                return f(result.get()).runParser(result.get(2), cont)
            else
                return cont(result)
            end
        end)
    end)
end
```

This way, it's tail calls all the way down! Admittedly, there's potential for `f` to overflow all on its own, but that would be a case of bad programming on the user's side, as `f` shouldn't go very deep at all.